# Writing High Performance Server. Which method?

Tags: unix, asynchronous, network-programming, io

if you would need to write a high performance server how would you do it?

- Using **asynchronous blocking** epoll / kqueue? 
  But how to handle the blocking System call epoll / kqueue here? Perhaps with a Main thread which uses worker Threads which perform the blocking epoll/kqueue ?
- Using libevent? Does it even differs from epoll/kqueue as it only capsulates different mechanisms like select, epoll, kqueue etc?
- Or instead using asynchronous blocking epoll/kqueue using **Asynchronous non blocking** libaio? But does it even support Sockets or just Disk IO?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: I guess that I would start with figuring out what it was supposed to serve and getting a *quantitative* definition of high performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use libevent.

It uses the best available mechanism on the target platform, whatever that mechanism may be; so, without changes, your program will use `kqueue` on BSD, `epoll(4)` on Linux, and whatever else is best on whatever else might exist, while still falling back to `select(2)` on old platforms, and somehow it also works on Windows.

Magical software. :)

Comment: Does it support multiple CPU-Cores?

Comment: @Filipe, yes, but not very transparently; if you want to use the event loop in multiple cores, you need to [start multiple event loops, one per participating thread / process](http://www.mail-archive.com/libevent-users@monkey.org/msg00403.html), and pass around descriptors as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [boost::Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/boost_asio.html)
It uses best non blocking IO per system

- epoll for linux
- kqueue for NIX like
- overlapped I/O on Windows

It can handle other streams as well (COM, files).
Concept is simple create io_service class and write handle (event like) classes to manage stream.